# CSS not working as expected in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have written the CSS for a "sticky" footer which means that the footer would always stick to the bottom of the page. Below is the CSS for the same -

```
footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e9eef2;
    min-height: 135px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This works in all browsers but Safari. In safari, it does not stick to the bottom and appears just where the content ends. Please help!

Comment: I don't see anything particularly sticky about that footer. Can we see the [rest of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided might not be helpful since you didn't upload the rest of your code. So from the code you provided, you did not add any property to make it fixed in the bottom or sticky.

So again from your code, I can recommend that you change your **position: relative** to **position: fixed**, then add these properties: **bottom: 0**; **left: 0**.

That code is supported in all browsers, including Safari.

However, there is also another option, by using  **position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky;** and by also adding the properties I mentioned above. Don't forget the -webkit- prefix, so it will be supported.

Either of the two options, it will run perfectly in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all history of the browser and cache then re try it.
Some times browser catch the previews styling till you clear all history and cache